How to use the parameter "allow_dash" in "typer.Option" or "typer.Argument" in the Python package "typer"?
I don't understand how to use the parameter allow_dash  in typer.Option or typer.Argument in the Python package typer.
I can only find this page Typer, saying
"allow_dash: If this is set to True, a single dash to indicate standard streams is permitted."
Here is my code:
import typer

app = typer.Typer()

@app.command()
def read_data(a: str = typer.Argument(..., allow_dash=True)):
    print(f"Data received from standard input: \n{a}")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()

Whether I set allow_dash=True or allow_dash=False, this code still cannot read from the standard streams.
Please teach me how to use this parameter allow_dash. Thank you.

How do you know whether the code can read from the standard streams?

I don't know. In fact, I don't even know how to use the parameter allow_dash. I just find a page saying  "allow_dash: If this is set to True, a single dash to indicate standard streams is permitted." However, it won't work.

Yes. How do you know that it won't work?

Because even I set allow_dash=True, the code won't allow me to read from the standard streams and I can only run this code through standard typer command (e.g., python test.py abcdefg)

Your code isn't trying to read from standard streams anywhere, I still don't understand how you know whether that works.
